# argocd cli json output

Tags: kubernetes, argocd, gitops

I'm trying to make argocd cli output yaml/json to prep it for script ingestion.

According to this PR: https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/pull/2551
It should be available but I can't find the option in cli help nor in documentation.

```
#argocd version:                                                                                                                                    
argocd: v2.1.2+7af9dfb
...
argocd-server: v2.0.3+8d2b13d
```

Answer (score 4):

Some commands accept the `-o json` flag to request JSON output.

Look in the [commands documentation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/tree/master/docs/user-guide/commands) to find commands which support that flag.

`argocd cluster list -o json`, for example, will return a JSON list of configured clusters. [The documentation](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/blob/caa246a38d56639f76ba0efb712967a191fddf44/docs/user-guide/commands/argocd_cluster_get.md#options) looks like this:

> ### Options
>
> ```
>    -h, --help            help for get
>    -o, --output string  
> Output format. One of: json|yaml|wide|server (default "yaml")
> ```

Comment: Yes Thank for answering. I now see it's not a global flag, my intended command doesn't.

https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/7676